# Do apparent magnitude (V) and photometric magnitude (specifically in optical V band between 500-600 nm) have a similar scale to stellar magnitude?

Tags: star, galaxy, astrophysics, cosmology, universe

I'm graphing a table and I used the magnitude values from this database
https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-4
(It's the V/19/data catalog for "Masses and Ages of stars in 68 open clusters", Piskunov 1980 in VizieR)

[image]
[image]

I wanted to know if this scale(V mag)  works in the same way as a stellar magnitude scale where the fainter objects have a higher magnitude number. Generally speaking for a star's magnitude number does a larger value automatically imply less intensity?
Also if anyone could refer to any databases that contain stellar magnitude values for different open galactic clusters that would be so helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Vmag IS apparent visual magnitude.